# can't use type stored in a type array

Tags: c#, inheritance, types

I have a base class called a, and it has a virtual function called Foo

```
class a
{
    public virtual void Foo() {}
}
```

And i have a bunch of other classes inheriting from it.

```
class B : A{}
class C : A{}
class D : A{}
class E : A{}
```

Now, i want to have an array of the types so i can choose one by random so i tried this:

```
class Boo
{
    Type[] options;
    public Boo()
    {
        options = new[]
        {
            typeof(B),
            typeof(C),
            typeof(D),
            typeof(E)
        };
    }
}
```

And then i want to choose one at random and use its Foo method and i did it like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
(options[rnd.Next(options.Length)] as A).Foo()
```

But this doesn't work, is there any way of accomplishing this?

(Btw, i didn't have a good name for this so if anyone has a better name they can feel free to edit :) )

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Any errors?

Comment: options contains type, where Foo() expects an instance.

Comment: `options[rnd.Next(options.Length)] as A` should be `null` so a `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

Comment: You misunderstood the Type Class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev,  it gives a conversion error for this part:
**(options[rnd.Next(options.Length)] as A)**
"cannot convert from...."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`options` should be an array of `A`-instances, not a `Type[]`.

```
class Boo {
    public A[] options;
    public Boo() {
        options = new[] {
            new B(),
            new C(),
            new D(),
            new E()
        };
    }
}
```

[C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8TuLpU)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because your `options` array holds the types themselves, not instances.

You can do something like

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var type = options[rnd.Next(options.Length)]
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as A;
instance.Foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke `Foo` you have to create an instance first, then invoke:

```
((options[rnd.Next(options.Length)].GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(null)) as A).Foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already described how to fix your original code.

However, as an alternative, you could just use a switch statement or similar approach:

```
public static A RandomlyCreateA(Random rng)
{
    switch (rng.Next(4))
    {
        case 0: return new B();
        case 1: return new C();
        case 2: return new D();
        case 3: return new E();

        default: throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't happen!");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use reflection to choose randomly from all types that inherit from `class A` (that are defined in the same assembly as `class A`):

```
public static A RandomlyCreateA(Random rng)
{
    var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(A)).GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(A))).ToArray();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(types[rng.Next(types.Length)]) as A;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but i want to avoid swtich statments, for better flexibility